# Where is the error in my javascript jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to write this piece of code to call info from a php page to show on an html page. Hopefully I got it right, but when I try opening it in browser, chrome gives me an error that there is a missing paranthesis but for the life of me I cannot find it. Any help would be appreciated!

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <title>Accounts</title>
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#info').onload = function() {
            var answer=$.get('account.php,' queryString, function(data) {
                $('#info').html(data);
            });
            var queryString="Hello, you are logged in as " + answer;
        };
    });
    </script>
      <form id="info">
      </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: what is the error in console

Comment: this code would never work anyways. $.get() doesn't return the ajax data. `answer` will be the jqhxr object, **NOT** whatever value you're trying to fetch from the server. Plus, `querystring` is undefined.

Answer (score 4):

You have comma inside the url string

```
var answer = $.get('account.php,'
                          _____^____
```

Put it outside like

```
var answer = $.get('account.php', queryString, function (data) {
   $('#info').html(data);
});
```

and error will be gone.

But as @MarcB have mentioned,

> this code would never work anyways. $.get() doesn't return the ajax
>   data. answer will be the jqhxr object, NOT whatever value you're
>   trying to fetch from the server.

You will need to modify the code as there are some issues in it.

- First, there is no `onload` property in jquery. Its a javascript event object which is used like:-

  ```
  window.onload=function(){// your logic here};
  ```
- `$.get()` doesn't return the ajax data. It will return ajax data in the callback function.
- Typo in your code as I have already mentioned above.
- `queryString` is `undefined` while you are trying to pass it to `.get()` as it has been declared afterwards.

You can do something like:-

```
$.get('account.php', 'Guest', function(answer) {
    var queryString="Hello, you are logged in as " + answer;
    $('#info').html(queryString);
});
```

More details on `.get()` method: [$.get() jQuery API Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)

Comment: You missed the problems with `.onload`

Answer (score 4):

You have multiple problems.

- There is no `onload` property on a jQuery object:
- The return value of `$.get` is just a jQuery `promise` object
- You have a missing comma after the URL (you have it inside the url string - typo)
- You are setting the value of `queryString` after using it, but creating it based on the result of the previous operation... Talk about endless knots!

You can replace all that functionality with a single jQuery `load()`

```
$(function(){
    $('#info').load('account.php');
});
```

### notes:

- `$(function(){` is just a handy shortcut for `$(document).ready(function(){`
- Why you expected *two return values* is beyond me at this point :)
- The `queryString` variable is undefined in your code, but if needed, just append the parameters to the URL.

Comment: Probably right. Although hard to see where the original `queryString` string was intended to be used

Comment: @RGraham: if needed they can append it to the URL.The original code is has way too many problems to even guess.